# Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'. Why?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a problem when binding an image from `DataGridView` to `PictureBox` and I get the following error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub BindToText()
    With dgv_EmployeeMainFile
        ... 
        Dim bytes As [Byte]() = .CurrentRow.Cells(31).Value
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(bytes)
        PictureEmp.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: apparently, `Cells(31)` contains a string.  If there is am ImageCOlumn somewhere you dont have to convert it to byte() tp show it elsewhere - it will be an image wrapped in Object

Comment: What do you expect to find in `.CurrentRow.Cells(31).Value`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Cells(31) contains Unicode character then you can use:

```
System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str)
```

For reference : https://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-string-byte-array-vbnet